# How to make part of the graphics gray (shaded) as in the picture?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I use SfChart.I use trackball and I want that when I move the trackball then the right part of the screen after the line becomes shaded as in the picture, how to do it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have analyzed your query and we have achieved your requirement “Make part of the graphics gray with trackball movement” with the help of RectangleAnnotation and Trackball created event in SfChart. Please find the code example below.

**CodeSnippet**:

MainPage.xaml

```
<chart:SfChart TrackballCreated="SfChart_TrackballCreated" >

. . .

<chart:SfChart.ChartAnnotations>
    <chart:RectangleAnnotation Y1="0" IsVisible="False"
                               FillColor="#80d3d3d3"
                               StrokeWidth="0"
                               x:Name="rectangleAnnotation" 
                               CoordinateUnit="Pixels" />
</chart:SfChart.ChartAnnotations>

<chart:SfChart.ChartBehaviors>
    <local:ChartTrackballExt x:Name="trackballBehavior" ShowLabel="False">
        <local:ChartTrackballExt.MarkerStyle>
            <chart:ChartTrackballMarkerStyle ShowMarker="False"/>
        </local:ChartTrackballExt.MarkerStyle>
        <local:ChartTrackballExt.LineStyle>
            <chart:ChartLineStyle StrokeColor="Black" StrokeWidth="2"/>
        </local:ChartTrackballExt.LineStyle>
    </local:ChartTrackballExt>
</chart:SfChart.ChartBehaviors>

</chart:SfChart>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private void SfChart_TrackballCreated(object sender, ChartTrackballCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    rectangleAnnotation.X1 = (e.ChartPointsInfo[0] as ChartPointInfo).XPosition;       
    if (!rectangleAnnotation.IsVisible)
    {
        rectangleAnnotation.IsVisible = true;
        var seriesBounds = (sender as SfChart).SeriesBounds;
        rectangleAnnotation.Y1 = seriesBounds.Top;
        rectangleAnnotation.Y2 = seriesBounds.Bottom;
        rectangleAnnotation.X2 = seriesBounds.Right;
    }
}

public class ChartTrackballExt : ChartTrackballBehavior
{
    protected override void OnTouchUp(float pointX, float pointY)
    {
        base.OnTouchUp(pointX, pointY);
        if (this.Chart.ChartAnnotations.Count > 0)
            (this.Chart.ChartAnnotations[0] as RectangleAnnotation).IsVisible = false;
    }
}
```

Also, we have attached the complete sample for your reference. Please find the sample from the below link.

Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ChartSample_Trackball-1332628840

**Output**:

[image]

For more details, please refer the below link
https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/charts/trackball
https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/charts/chartannotation#shape-annotation